# Cancellation law of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why does cancellation law not hold true for matrices I.e if A,B and C are three matrices of orders that are suitable for multiplication such that
A.B=A.C
Then even if A≠0 still B may or may not be equal to C

Comment: Unlike real numers, `A≠0` is not a sufficient condition for matrix $A$ to have a multiplicative inverse, which is what the cancellation law relies upon..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an example: Say $A=\begin{pmatrix}1& 0 \\0&0\end{pmatrix},$ $B= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $C= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}.$ Then $AB= AC = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ but $B\ne C.$ The key is that $A$ is not an invertible matrix. Cancellation only holds when $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Okay...I got your point.thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a matrix is a linear transformation. 
If two vectors after transformed by a transformation can be the same vector. 
Then the cancellation law doesn't hold in matrix